# Firebase Internal Error when authenticating with signInWithMoralisByEvm and Magic Provider

Tags: firebase, magic-sdk

I’m trying to authenticate in Firebase using Magic Wallet via signInWithMoralis function. But I get Firebase Internal Error. I’ve integrated Metamask, Coinbase Wallet and WalletConnect without problems.

I repeated the same procedure with others wallet. Use signInWithMoralisByEvm with the provider from magic. I signed the message but then the error is thrown.
Here is a screenshot of the error. Not much information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcqFE.png)